"Received NaN for the `children` attribute" warning
I am building a tic tac toe web app. When I try it and click the button "Ver Ranking", it throws me a warning I do not know how to handle:
Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
    at td
    at tr
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at div
    at Component /./src/app/ranking/page.js:20:82)

I am building the app using Next.js 14 and this is my page.js code:
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Button from "@/components/Button";
import { getRanking, updateRanking } from "@/lib/apiCalls";

const winCombs = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

export default function Home() {
  const [userTurn, setUserTurn] = useState(true);
  const [boardState, setBoardState] = useState({
    0: "",
    1: "",
    2: "",
    3: "",
    4: "",
    5: "",
    6: "",
    7: "",
    8: "",
  });
  const [isWinner, setIsWinner] = useState(false);
  const [draw, setDraw] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [winnerCombo, setWinnerCombo] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userTurn) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        aiPlay(boardState);
      }, 1000);
    }
    checkResult(boardState);
  }, [boardState, userTurn]);

  const aiPlay = async (board) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(board),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setBoardState(data);
      setUserTurn(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const updateBoard = (idx) => {
    if (!boardState[idx] && !isWinner) {
      let value = userTurn === true ? "X" : "O";
      setBoardState({ ...boardState, [idx]: value });
      setUserTurn(!userTurn);
    }
  };

  const checkResult = async (board) => {
    // board is filled
    const allFilled = Object.values(board).every((cell) => cell !== "");
    // state of the ranking at the moment
    const actualRanking = await getRanking();
    if (allFilled && !isWinner) {
      console.log(userTurn);
      setIsWinner(true);
      setDraw(true);
      setTitle("EMPATE!");
      await updateRanking("-", actualRanking);
      return;
    }
    for (let comb of winCombs) {
      const [a, b, c] = comb;
      if (board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c]) {
        if (!userTurn) {
          console.log(userTurn);
          setIsWinner(true);
          setWinnerCombo([a, b, c]);
          setTitle("VICTORIA!");
          await updateRanking("X", actualRanking);
          return;
        }
        if (userTurn) {
          console.log(userTurn);
          setIsWinner(true);
          setWinnerCombo([a, b, c]);
          setTitle("DERROTA!");
          await updateRanking("O", actualRanking);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setBoardState({
      0: "",
      1: "",
      2: "",
      3: "",
      4: "",
      5: "",
      6: "",
      7: "",
      8: "",
    });
    setUserTurn(true);
    setIsWinner(false);
    setDraw(false);
    setWinnerCombo([]);
    setTitle("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-1 mb-4 font-bold">
        <h1>Tres en Raya</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div className="text-center text-2xl mb-2">
          <p>{userTurn === true ? "Es tu turno!" : "Turno de la IA"}</p>
          <p
            className={`text-sm mb-2 ${
              !isWinner && !draw ? "text-green-600" : "text-red-600"
            }`}
          >{`${
            isWinner || draw ? "Partida finalizada" : "Juego en progreso"
          }`}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(3,1fr)] gap-2">
          {[...Array(9)].map((v, idx) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={idx}
                className={`bg-[#eee] ${
                  userTurn ? "shadow-[0px_4px_#ddd]" : "shadow-none"
                } text-center text-[64px] leading-[100px] font-[bold] w-[100px] h-[100px] cursor-pointer rounded-lg ${
                  winnerCombo.includes(idx)
                    ? "bg-black text-white shadow-none"
                    : ""
                }`}
                onClick={() => {
                  updateBoard(idx);
                }}
              >
                {boardState[idx]}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      {isWinner || draw ? (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-6">
          <p className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">{title}</p>
          <Button text="Volver a Jugar" action={reset} />
        </div>
      ) : null}
      <Button
        text="Ver Ranking"
        action={() => {
          router.push("/ranking");
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

And I created a ranking page which code is:
"use client";

import Button from "@/components/Button";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getRanking } from "@/lib/apiCalls";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Component() {
  const [ranking, setRanking] = useState({});
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    getRankingData();
  }, []);

  const getRankingData = async () => {
    const rankingData = await getRanking();
    setRanking(rankingData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4 md:px-6 py-8">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-between mb-6">
        <h1 className="font-bold mb-4 md:mb-0">Ranking</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="border rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <table className="w-full table-auto">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="w-[200px] px-4 py-3 text-left font-bold">
                Jugador
              </th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Victorias</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Derrotas</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Empates</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">PJs</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 font-medium">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                  <div className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <span>U</span>
                  </div>
                  <span>Usuario</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerX?.won}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerX?.lost}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerX?.tied}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">
                {ranking?.playerX?.won +
                  ranking?.playerX?.lost +
                  ranking?.playerX?.tied}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="px-4 py-3">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                  <div className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <span>IA</span>
                  </div>
                  <span>IA</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerO?.won}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerO?.lost}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking?.playerO?.tied}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">
                {ranking?.playerO?.won +
                  ranking?.playerO?.lost +
                  ranking?.playerO?.tied}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <Button
        text="Volver a Jugar"
        action={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          router.push("/");
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

In this last page I get the data from a database and show it in a ranking table. Here it is the getRanking method:
export const getRanking = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    if (data) return data[0];
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

I tried to modify the Button component but it did not solve the problem. Could be useEffect() in the ranking page the key point?
If you need further info I can provide it. Thanks in advance!

In the ranking page I modified a few things below is the code:
"use client";

import Button from "@/components/Button";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getRanking } from "@/lib/apiCalls";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
export default function Component() {
  const [ranking, setRanking] = useState({
    playerX: { won: 0, lost: 0, tied: 0 },
    playerO: { won: 0, lost: 0, tied: 0 },
  });
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRankingData = async () => {
      try {
        const rankingData = await getRanking();
        if (rankingData) {
          setRanking(rankingData);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failed to fetch ranking data:", error);
      }
    };

    getRankingData();
  }, []);

  const safeSum = (a, b, c) => {
    return (a || 0) + (b || 0) + (c || 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4 md:px-6 py-8">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-between 
mb-6">
        <h1 className="font-bold mb-4 md:mb-0">Ranking</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="border rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <table className="w-full table-auto">
          <head>
            <tr>
              <th className="w-[200px] px-4 py-3 text-left font-
bold">Jugador</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Victorias</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Derrotas</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">Empates</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-3 text-right font-bold">PJs</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 font-medium">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                  <div className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <span>U</span>
                  </div>
                  <span>Usuario</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerX.won}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerX.lost}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerX.tied}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">
                {safeSum(ranking.playerX.won, ranking.playerX.lost, ranking.playerX.tied)}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="px-4 py-3">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                  <div className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <span>IA</span>
                  </div>
                  <span>IA</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerO.won}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerO.lost}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">{ranking.playerO.tied}</td>
              <td className="px-4 py-3 text-right">
                {safeSum(ranking.playerO.won, ranking.playerO.lost, ranking.playerO.tied)}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <Button
        text="Volver a Jugar"
        action={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          router.push("/");
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

please check this code if this works.
changes...
.....The ranking state is initialized with default values to avoid any undefined issues.
.....using a try-catch block inside the getRankingData function to handle any potential errors when fetching the ranking data.
.....The safeSum function ensures that if any of the values (won, lost, tied) are undefined, they default to 0.
and what I use if I get some type of error or something....I add console.log() statement to see where is the problem is occurring.
and if by any chance you are using typescript then please assign types of your state do avoid compile time error.
hope this will help.

It works! Thanks you so much!
